# Excel combo box bug in protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I protect my sheet and select the list from a `combobox`, another combobox shows up at a random place (marked by the red circle in the picture below).

I have not placed any comboboxes there, but it keeps showing, and I need to select an empty cell for that to disappear. Does anybody know how to fix this bug ?

[image]

this is my combo box code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice: 2018/9/21
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr

    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
            End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the problem with using ActiveX controls on worksheets. This has been there for so many years. i noticed it for the first time in Excel 2003 and since then I have stopped using ActiveX controls on worksheets. Use form controls.

Comment: BTW you can also use Data Validation list in this case:)

Comment: can data validation do autofill text/auto search the item when I type it ? because I tried using data validation and I cant do that. for example: when I type 'ca' the cell know that Im typing cash so they auto complete it to cash

Comment: because there is another combo box that is use to input purchased item from inventory list and my inventory list is so much

Comment: @Siddharth Rout must be a very persistent bug if MS has not managed to remotely fix the issue in 16 years time. This has been a very common problem in my projects, I would really like to see it gone.

Comment: I will get back to this thread later tonight. In office... stuck with some stupid deadlines...